# Store multiple DOM Elements in an Array with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs, evaluate

For the last couple of hours I have been trying to query DOM elements and store them in an array with CasperJS, so then after that, I can loop through them and fire a click event.

Let's say, my markup is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to store each `<li>` an an Array, then loop through, fire a Click event, then take a capture.

This is one of the things I tried:

```
var listItems = [];

casper.start();

casper.open(urlHere, function () {
    listItems.push(this.evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
    }));

    this.echo(listItems);
});
```

It returns `[ , , , ]` which basically means they are all `null`.

Can someone please direct me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
var listItems = [];

casper.start(urlHere, function () {
    listItems = this.evaluate(function () {
        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
        return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) {
            return node.textContent;
        });
    });

    this.echo(listItems);
});
```

Basically, you can't return values which are not serializable from `this.evaluate()`, it's rather [well explained](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.evaluate) in the docs.

Comment: how do i go deeper like grabbing the content inside LI

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about CasperJS but an array is considered an object in JavaScript so an array would have a type of Object. Have you tried looping through it using a for loop?

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<listItems.length;i++) {
    var item = listItems[i];
}
```

Alternatively if you have an actual object containing your list item objects you can do the following:

```
for(i in listItems) {
    if(listItems.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
        var item = listItems[i];
    }
}
```

Edit: This is just to check that you actually have a valid array containing your items.

Comment: Hey Jon, I tried both options already but all it returns is `null`. This is getting boring now... Thanks anyway